# automatically split data in list and order list elements and send to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

I have recently created a GUI, which contents tables. User can insert values in cells. As shown figur below.

[image]

I want to use values to make some calculation based on values given by user. Rows can be added and removed based on choice of user. with other word, the data I get from user could come from just one row or several rows.

I manage to obtain all values from tables automatically and assign them to python list. Each row gives 5 elements in the list.

I have achieved that. Data in python list have to be processed and organised. This is exactly I want to have help. Because few dags I have been thinking, and I can not figure out, how to continue...

Python data as list from table. as an example.

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, '', 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

What I want to achieve!

I want to split list into 3 times `len(data)`.

I have also achieved this.

```
def split_seq(seq, num_pieces):
    start = 0
    for i in range(num_pieces):
        stop = start + len(seq[i::num_pieces])
        yield seq[start:stop]
        start = stop

for data in split_seq(data, int(len(data)/5)):
    print(data)
```

Output would be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['', 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

The difficulty part starts here.

I want to take each splitted list and throw them into an if condition and store values as variables and message those values to an external function.

Something like this below:

```
for i in range(len(splitted_list1)):
    if splitted_list1[0] == '':
       do nothing
    else:
       x_+str(i)= splitted_list1[i]
       externalfunc(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)

for i in range(len(splitted_list2)):
    if splitted_list2[0] == '':
       do nothing
    else:
       x_+str(i)= splitted_list2[i]
       externalfunc(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)

continues depending on number of splitted_lists

..............
```

I appreciate any help and you are welcome to come with another idea to come around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one single list and pass that to `externalfunc`.

The line `x_+str(i)= ...` is going to be interpreted as `x_"0"= ...` or whatever number eventually. The function is going to take in a possibly unknown number of variables. You can just group each "variable" into one list and index them based on the number instead. Which you already have. Each one would be in `splitted_list0`, `splitted_list1`, etc.

However, you do not need to asynchronously return the different lists. Instead, you can split the lists and put them in one larger list. This is a two-dimensional array. Seems scary but it's just some lists inside another list.

Now to pass each number to the `externalfunc` you can use each split list and pass it as an argument. Basically resulting in `externalfunc(splitted_list0)` and so on.

The final code ends up something like the following:

```
# Split the data into seperate lists:
split_lists = [data[i*(len(data)/3):(i+1)*(len(data)/3)] for i in range(3)]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, '', 11, 12, 13, 14] becomes
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['', 11, 12, 13, 14]]

# Pass each list to the external function:
for i in range(split_lists):
  externalfunc(split_lists[i])
  # split_lists[i] will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] or [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], etc.
```

Note that the `3` in the first line of code can be changed to be any number smaller than the length of the list `data`. This is just the number of lists to split the data into. Remember to change every 3 if it's hardcoded or just add a variable. Finally, the function `externalfunc` will have the list of 5 numbers as the first and only argument of the function.

```
def externalfunc(nums):
  for n in nums:
    # n = each number in the list
    # do something with n, write it somewhere, store it, print it.
    print(n)
```

Comment: I think I can use your idea. I would try it and would hear from me tomorrow according European time. Thanks for your effort and help.

Comment: The provided code above gives some errors when it runs. but I have gotten your idea. I would fix and use it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pavel.D Awesome! It's been a while since I've used Python but if there are errors I hope they're easy to fix. Good luck on your programming!